# zabbix calculated itens: convert time from epochtime to human

Tags: linux, zabbix, zabbix-agent, convert, epoch-time

i havem a problem, im new on zabbix and have isues in epochtime

i create a calculated item on zabbix, formula: "now()"
[image: photo1]

but, its showing in not human format

[image: photo1z]

how i can make a exemple, a xmas countdawn, like this

formula: "day 1 of january 2024" - now()

and show me: Xdays